# Numeric matrix for apriori

Tags: r, bioconductor, apriori

I have a numeric matrix with 20 rows and 10 columns, I would like to Apply apriori, but how to discritize this data and how to transform it to transactions? the dataset contains rownames and columnames.
Is this correct?

```
library("arules")
write(mat, file = "deee.csv", sep = ",")
tr <- read.transactions("deee.csv")
apriori_rule <- apriori(tr, parameter = list(supp = 0.1, conf = 0.1))
```

---

My data matrix:

```
          A           B                      C                     D
t1               6.960722         7.095137         7.165269         7.377422
t2               8.305320         8.215023         8.690460         8.346847
t3                …..
```

T1,T2,T3: are the transactions 
A, B and C are the attributes, 
the numeric values are the  values of the attributes in the transactions (lines).

Comment: I am using a 'arules' package

Answer (score 0):

Coerce your matrix to a `data.frame` (with `as.data.frame`) and then use `discretize()` before calling apriori.

Comment: Hi @Michael , Thanks. When I use discretize() after as.data.frame() I have this error: fault(x, breaks = breaks, labels = labels, include.lowest = include.lowest, : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: You can either discretize columns individually (with `discretize()`) or discretize a data.frame with `discretizeDF()` (see `? discretize`)